Do I need transit visa going to France?
Do I need a transit visa to France (layover for 2 or 3 hours only)? I'm in the UK travelling with my child who's a British citizen and I'm a Filipino citizen (I need to visit my mother in the PHILIPPINE, it’s emergency purposes travel).
We missed our flights the other day because I was not aware that I needed a transit visa to Dublin, the worst part is if my flight was before 4 pm I don't need transit visa but my flight was 4:40 pm so they asked me for my transit visa that I was not aware of. Please help answer my question. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Yes, you need a visa. Are the two flights on the same ticket, or are they booked separately? This would change the type of visa you need. But if it’s urgent you should probably consider a different connection. Among Schengen countries, only France requires an airport transit visa for Filipinos. But that only applies if both flights are on a single ticket, self transfers would require a visa.

thank you for answering my question. I cancelled all my flights before it was too late and they refunded haft of the price I paid. now I need to book again and ask lots of questions on this site so it will not make the same mistakes again, especially when I'm with my child and thinking of my mum.

@MHermosa If you have questions about Schengen visas, reading the existing questions here might be helpful. You can check visa requirements on the IATA website before you book a flight
